# visual studio code delegate extension

Tags: typescript, delegates, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently using more delegate than inheritance in my typescript code. I would like to find some extension to generate delegate method in visual studio code like it already exist in netbeans for java.

Do you guys know an extension to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean  `=>` arrow functions in typescripts?

Comment: Delegation is just how things work in JavaScript. There's almost no code to write at all. If you're trying to do something weird with classes and delegation I would avoid it and just use standard patterns like passing Arrow functions as mentioned above